# Cannot open file glu32.lib

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I created a new project in my Qt 5.4.1 opengl 64 bit. When i tried to build and run my project, I get LINK 1104: cannot open file glu32.lib. I searched my entire pc but i couldn't find glu32.lib file anywhere neither I could find opengl32.lib. I am very new to Qt so, even in Kits I have this Desktop opengl 64bit automatically detected, but side of this it has exclamatory icon. Do everyone has this icon or I have made some error?

This is error in Compile Output section

```
11:27:17: Running steps for project untitled20...
11:27:17: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:27:17: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\untitled20.exe @C:\Users\jas\AppData\Local\Temp\untitled20.exe.4652.94.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glu32.lib'
jom: C:\Users\jas\Documents\build-untitled20-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2013_OpenGL_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\untitled20.exe] Error 1104
jom: C:\Users\jas\Documents\build-untitled20-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MSVC2013_OpenGL_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
11:27:20: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled20 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
11:27:20: Elapsed time: 00:03.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you search for all the places in your computer where you have glu32.lib? The problem you are facing could be due to 2 reasons:

1. The default location where Qt is looking for glu32.lib may not have it (less likely)
2. The default location where Qt is looking for glu32.lib may have spaces in its path name.

Comment: Please don't spread misinformation. OpenGL is one of those corner cases where no extra libraries must be installed. Since OpenGL is part of the OS ABIs of Windows, Linux, MacOS X and other OSs, it is mandatory for platform compiler toolchains (MSVC, MinGW, and so on) to ship the proper linker definition files. MSVC and MinGW have the full set of ABI compliant OpenGL development files (opengl32.lib and glu32.lib). The DLLs themself are part of the Windows OS installation. No extra development files must be installed!

Comment: Are you sure about that ? In that case where in a newly installed Windows operating system would you find opengl32.lib and glu32.lib? Also, ever heard of DirectX on Windows? Windows uses DirectX for 3d rendering and as far as I know, does not ship OpenGl as part of the operating system. But I would be pleased to be corrected regarding this.

Comment: Absolutely sure. The `opengl32.lib` and `glu32.lib` files are part of the development tools and you can find them in the default installation of the Windows Platform SDK, Visual Studio, the Windows DDK and MinGW. The `.dll` files are part of the standard Windows installation. **You don't need to install extra, special SDK files for OpenGL development**. There are 3rd party libraries to make certain tedious tasks simple (extension loading, creating OpenGL contexts and windows). But none of these 3rd party libs are required for OpenGL development.

Comment: Each and every version of Windows since Windows-NT 4 and Windows 95B is shipping `%WINDIR%/System32/opengl32.dll`. And no, Windows is not using "DirectX" for 3D rendering. Direct3D is *"a"* API for accessing GPUs, not *"the"* API Windows uses. And OpenGL is a completely independent API provided through `opengl32.dll` and implemented as part of the GPU drivers in form of a so called ICD (Installable Client Driver) that hooks into the functions provided by `opengl32.dll`. In Windows OpenGL operates completely independent from DirectX.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the clarification. Still, seems like his project requires a static library version of the glu library. It might be in his Visual Studio SDK folder but he is not able to point to it, or has not done it yet.

Comment: On Windows things are a bit tricky. The Linker will **always** ingest a static style `.lib` file. However this "library" will either contain the full library code (static linking) *or* it provides the symbol table, linker stubs and name of the DLL to resolve. When you build a DLL you always end up with two files: The DLL itself and the linker definitions `.lib` file. DLLs lack the information required by the linker, so unlike ELF `.so` you can't just point the linker to the DLL, which is why you need the `.lib`.

Comment: Right, but on my own system, I did find the DLL glu32.dl and opengl32.dll but not the corresponding lib versions. So I suspect his Qt framework comes with a .lib version of the aforementioned libraries.

Comment: The lib files should be found in the compiler installation directory; alongside `.lib`s for *kernel32*, *shell32*, *gdi32*, *user32* and all the other Windows cruft.